# ImportError: cannot import name 'VirtualDeviceConfiguration' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context'

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Getting import error while trying to download fashion_mnist data

Below is the script that I used in spyder.
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist

Tensorflow version
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.1.0

Comment: Can you provide more information like if you are using GPU and virtual environment?